# Show custom event parameters in Google Analytics for Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm using multiple features of Firebase for an iOS in Swift. I'm having problems seeing the results of some of my analytics events. I have a Store View in the app where the users and choose to buy the premium version of the app while they still are on a free trial. But this Store view is also shown as a paywall when their free trial has expired. 
So I track an analytics event when this view is shown. I call the event `"did_show_chop_store"` and I include a custom event parameter called `"is_paywall"`, which can either be `"true"` or `"false"` (as `String`). Here is how I track it:

```
func trackStore(as paywall: Bool) {
    let params: [String:Any] = ["is_paywall": paywall.asString()]
    Analytics.logEvent("did_show_chop_store", parameters: params)
}
```

where `.asString()` is an extension to `Bool` that converts the value to the above mentioned strings.

When adding Custom parameter reporting as described [here](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7397304?hl=en) (added as a "Text" parameter), I'm expecting to see the distribution between `"true"` and `"false"` in the small `"is_paywall"` chart under the specific event in thee Google Analytics for Firebase console, but in stead I see no data:

[image]

I also don't see any data about `"is_paywall"` when exporting as CSV.
**What am I doing wrong?** or is this whole Google Analytics for Firebase just much buggy?

Comment: Just making sure.. have you added your new parameters in the `Custom definitions`? https://stackoverflow.com/a/69178883/12695188