# Filter GA events by event's parameters

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-analytics

I'm sending analytics from my flutter app. I'm adding parameters to each event:

For instance:

```
  void onGroupVote(bool isBusiness) { 
      analytics.logEvent(
          name: "group_vote",
          parameters: <String, dynamic> {
              'is_business': isBusiness,
      },
  );}
```

I find my events in GA, but I can't filter them based on my parameters (in that case `is_business`).

[image]

Can I filter events by params in GA? Or my only option is using BigQuery?

Comment: I think you have to go to the "configure" section of the main menu (not in your screenshot), go to "custom definitions" and create a custom dimension from your parameter. Then you should be able to use it in a filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding new parameters to `Custom definitions` enables us to use them on filters.

Go `Configute` -> `Custom definitions` -> `Create Custom definitions`.

[image]

Fully credit to @Eike Pierstorff